# Am I asking too many questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently studying wavelets and have noticed there aren't many existing references for the questions I'm asking. Is it okay that I'm submitting multiple questions before getting answers? I don't want to come off as spammy.

Comment: That's good to hear. I'm trying to determine if implementing a CWT and DWT on a GPU would offer increased computation speed.

Comment: If it's not the same question multiple times it's OK. I did notice that suddenly there was more wavelet questions than usually. I thought maybe wavelets have somehow gained popularity lately. :D

Comment: If $n+1$ is a significant jump over $n$, it tells you something about $n$...